# Dropdown Menu with 20+ items gets cut off by a views content rotor

Tags: views, 6, routes

I'm trying to spruce up a Drupal 6 site, but I'm running into some issues with a views slideshow (specifically, [rotorbanner](http://drupal.org/project/rotor)) and having a menu with ~20 items.

When the menu expands, I can see all the links, but whenever I mouseover on a link that's within the "slider" block, the list disappears.

My thought was to fix this by just making the menu two column, but I'm running some difficulties with that and maybe fixing this will be easier.

I'd prefer not having 20 menu items, but that is the way my org does things, alas : )

For an example, go [this](http://www.c-institute.com/) dev site and hover over the "networks" section on the menu

Thanks!

Comment: Well, I messed around with the z-index value on the menu, and it seems to overlay the slideshow in Chrome on my Dev Machine, but when I try it in firefox or chrome (on another machine) it still appears "under" the slider.

Answer (score 1):

This is an awfully localized question, but I got this to work fine in Chrome and Firefox by adding:

```
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
```

to the slideshow block (`<div id="block-views-speakerslider-block_1">`) or any of its containers (`<div id="wrapper">`, `<div id="content">`, etc)

Comment: Thanks Laxman! That seems to have done it. I'm sorry for the localized question. Now I just have to find a way to make it two column. Oh Joy : )